# find command - syntax with -exec handle

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find, gzip

**Background and problem:**

I am using a find command to gzip all files that match my criteria:

```
sudo -u userAccount -i find /apps/server/userAccount/logs/. -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec gzip {} \;
```

This will go ahead and compress all files against my criteria but I don't want to be prompted to overwrite -- I want to be able to automagically skip and file that already exists as I'm dealing with sensitive data and cannot risk losing anything.

So far, I have tried:

1. *statement as above* -exec yes n | gzip {} \;
2. *statement as above* -exec [an if statement to determine if a file already exists]

None of these work due to find statement syntax errors.

**Question:**

Does anybody know how I can use either method above with my find statement?

**Update:**

I attempted to use:

```
sudo -u userAccount -i find /apps/server/userAccount/logs/. -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c "yes n | gzip {}" \;
```

But I just get scrolling 'y' characters returned to the console until I CTRL-C. Any suggestions?

Comment: The easiest way is to write a shell script that does what you want, and use `-exec scriptname {} \;`.

Comment: You can't put a pipe after `-exec`. That pipes the output of `find` to the next command.

Answer (score 2):

The command after `-exec` is not run by a shell, it's executed directly by `find`, so it can't use shell metacharacters or builtins. If you need to use the shell, you have to invoke it explicitly:

```
-exec bash -c "yes n | gzip {}" \;
```

Comment: so when I use this with my command, I am no getting cascading 'y' characters until my console errors out. I am using this command ---> sudo -u userAccount -i find /apps/server/userAccount/logs/. -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c "yes n | gzip {}" \;

Comment: There may be quoting issues with nesting the command inside `sudo`. Can you try it using `sudo -s` to get a shell command prompt, then type the command as I gave it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use pipes to the gzip command, you can use a case to test your file type.

```
find $PATH_TO_LOGS -maxdepth 1 -mtime +$SOME_NUMBER_OF_DAYS -exec sh -c "case {} in *.gz) ;; *)  gzip '{}' ;; esac;" \;
```

Of course, this depends upon your file names ending in the traditional `.gz` extension.  Benefits of this is that you can also process other file types by extension in this form.

Also, if you really don't want to lose anything, and you can't depend upon a backup copy, it might be a good idea to instead timestamp the files and simply incur the storage space hit.

```
find $PATH_TO_LOGS -maxdepth 1 -mtime +$SOME_NUMBER_OF_DAYS -exec gzip -N {} \;
```